# Does Firefox pipeline requests?

Tags: firefox, request-pipeline

Does Firefox pipeline requests? If not by default, can it be configured to do so?

Firefox downloads the main html file. Then extracts all the auxiliary files it needs to download. What next? Does it send out the first request and wait for the response, then the next request and so on? Or does it send out all the requests at once without waiting?

Edit: Version 55.0 or later.

Comment: Possibly specifying the version may help provide a more informative answer.

Comment: @norok2 Edited.